# accessing a file in windows7 using C# Code by providing administrative credentials

Tags: c#, windows-7

How could i access a file of Windows folder in windows 7 using C# code.
i want to access that file using administrator username password, instead of asking user to access file "AS ADMINISTRATOR".

Comment: you mean you want to hardcode admin password into your program?

Comment: yes. instead of requesting administrator access using UAC i want to provide password as hard coded in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something similar to this: [A small C# Class for impersonating a User](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User)

P.S. Think about consequences of hardcoding an admin password in the code.

Comment: by this impersonation class i can access files list but could not access any file in those list.